# UWP Service Reference - Generate Task based operations is the only option

Tags: c#, wcf, uwp

I recently just published a small collection of WCF services. When I went into my UWP app to add references I only see the option to generate task based operations. I am a fan of async operations, I also remember this being a feature previously so what is the deal?

Screenshot of the section:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Probably need to clear up a little terminology here. The "asynchronous operations" option that is grayed out refers to the [Asychronous Programming Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152938(v=vs.110).aspx) (i.e. BeginXXX, EndXXX methods) where as "task-based operations" refer to the [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175(v=vs.110).aspx) with which you can async/await.

Both are forms of asynchronous operation so it is unclear which you refer to when you say "I am a fan of async operations". I imagine you want to use the async/await keywords so the "task based operations" option is actually the one you want to use.

Comment: I want to declare client.on...completed += CompletedEvent;